# Manage text excerpts with tags for metadata and mine with R or RStudio?

Tags: r, text, storage, metadata, extract

I want to store text excerpts, or long texts (not 100 page books though), add tags (many, unlimited, like 100 tags or more) and mine/explore it with R or RStudio. I can do that on Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04 (Windows is the preference). What is the default way to do this? What software do you use for this? The texts will more likely be extracted offline, so for ex it shouldn't have anything to do with Wordpress.

Comment: There are lots of text mining packages such as `tidytext` (https://www.tidytextmining.com/). Storage is a different issue.

Comment: Yeah it's more about the storage though, if there is a very good solution that would work better with Python I could use it too